# How do I take 2 inputs from 2 listboxes, and tell them to do something?

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm taking a C# Intro course, and everything has been fairly easy up until now for me. I'm trying to make a convert application which requires the user to select an input, and output (two separate list boxes). I don't know how to tell my program to convert B to A, or C to A, and etc.

How do I grab inputs from listboxes, and combine them?

Comment: Are you trying to insert into the listboxes or from listbixes?

Comment: Well I tried doing "unconverted = unconvertedListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();". Hoping that it would send the selected item to unconverted. The full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/zL6Y0yNh).

Comment: WPF Or Windows forms, or ASP ?